# AWK Different Validation on Different Line Start

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I have data

with

```
90|1234|10:50|Y
91|1234|JOHN|john@domain.com|alert
92|1234|Student|MIB Alerts
```

Note: $2 is key value & it has some meaning in next logic

I want to do different validation

```
for line starting with 90, NF=4, $2 Numeric, $3 Time, $4 Y/N
for line starting with 91, NF=5, $2 Non Empty, $3 Email ID
for line starting with 92, NF=4, $2 Numeric
```

I ended up Splitting files according to 90, 91 & 92 values $1 start

using

```
grep "^90" filename | awk -F '|' 'NF == 4 && $2 ~  /^[0-9]*$/ && $3 ~ /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} $/ && $4 ~/^[YN]$/' >> file90.txt
grep "^91" filename | awk -F '|' 'NF == 5 && $2 ~  /^[0-9]*$/ && !length($3) && $4 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.]+@[[:alnum:]_]+[.][[:alnum:]]+$/' >> file91.txt  
grep "^92" filename | awk -F '|' 'NF == 4 && $2 ~  /^[0-9]*$/' >> file92.txt
```

then

```
cat file92.txt >> file91.txt
cat file91.txt >> file90.txt
```

With some changes this model works for me but it has 2 disadvantages:

1. It changes the file as 90 remains on top then 91  then 92 [In incoming file records can come in any pattern, 91 may come on top]
2. Multiple files, Splits & join
3. I feel i am using grep needlessly

Can someone help me in doing this in single AWK script or statement

Comment: Add `$1 == "90"` to the first condition, `$1 == "91"` to the second one, etc.

Comment: you say if ($1 == "90") {...} else if  ($1 == "91") {...}

Comment: and wrap all of your tests into 1 awk program. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the conditions on `$1` to each validation.

```
awk -F'|' '
    $1 == "90" && NF == 4 && $2 ~  /^[0-9]*$/ && $3 ~ /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} $/ && $4 ~/^[YN]$/ { print }
    $1 == "91" && NF == 5 && $2 ~  /^[0-9]*$/ && !length($3) && $4 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.]+@[[:alnum:]_]+[.][[:alnum:]]+$/ { print }
    $1 == "92" && NF == 4 && $2 ~  /^[0-9]*$/ { print }' filename > result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks :), I was not knowing solution was this straight forward

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you define a function for each positive test you want to make on a field and then just use the (negated when appropriate) functions in each validation rule:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function isNumeric(val)  { return (val == val+0)                }
function isTime(val)     { return (val ~ /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/) }
function isEmpty(val)    { return (val == "")                   }
function isYN(val)       { return (val ~ /^[YN]$/)              }
function isEmailId(val)  { return (val ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.]+@[[:alnum:]_]+[.][[:alnum:]]+$/) }

BEGIN { FS="|" }
($1==90) && (NF==4) && isNumeric($2) && isTime($3) && isYN($4)
($1==91) && (NF==5) && !isEmpty($2) && isEmailId($3)
($1==92) && (NF==4) && isNumeric($2)

$ awk -f tst.awk file
90|1234|10:50|Y
92|1234|Student|MIB Alerts
```

That way the implementation of the test is separate from the application of the test so you can change the implementation independently of the code that uses the test, and you don't need to duplicate test implementations on different lines, and it makes your code much clearer.

Do you understand why I say to only define "positive functions"? Because if you define:

```
function isNonEmpty(val)    { return (val != "")                   }
```

and then some time in future you need a test for empty you end up writing:

```
.... && !isNonEmpty(..) ...
```

i.e. you introduce a double negative. Don't write negative code and then you cannot end up with the dreaded double negative code.

Comment: Thanks ED, This really helps me in solving more complex problems +1